# error can not find the symbol client hander

Tags: java, sockets

i am trying to run a client server javaapplication but i am getting an error when i run it that it can not find the clienthander symbol on line 43: BankServer.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
ClientHander client = new ClientHander(x);

```
package com.mycompany.bankserver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class BankServer extends Thread {
   
    public ServerSocket server;  

    public BankServer(int port) throws IOException {
        server = new ServerSocket(9310);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        BankServer listener = new BankServer(9310);
        listener.start();                
        System.out.println("Press enter to stop server");
        input.nextLine();
        listener.interrupt();                
    }
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try {
                Socket x = server.accept();
                ClientHander client = new ClientHander(x);
                client.start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(BankServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The ClientHander class is unknown

Comment: how do i make it known

Comment: where comes it from?

Comment: another file in the same package

Comment: hmm.. maybe typo, ClientHander instead of ClientHandler ?

Comment: no the name of the file is clienthander

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244615/discussion-between-tomysek-and-george-derderian).